# Using multiple colors within a compound glyph

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to have multiple parts of a compound glyph rendered in different colours, but the resulting compound glyph is incorrectly rendered as separate glyphs, rather than one multicoloured compound glyph.

What could I be doing wrong or missing herein?

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif Devanagari}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\newcommand{\green}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}

\begin{document}

श्री:
    
श्\green{र}\red{ी}ः 

\end{document}
```

Output with the "Noto Serif Devanagari" font looks like this (both the lines are supposed to be identical, except for the colours)

[image: Noto Serif Devanagari]

With "Lohit Devanagari" font:

[image: Lohit Devanagari]

The font "Vesper Libre" renders multicolored compounds, but the compound glyph itself is incorrect (the first line, without colours is wrongly rendered):

[image: Vesper Libre]

I'm on Linux with xalatex

Comment: Xelatex inserts the colour commands between the glyphs, so the font-shaping engine does not see the glyphs as next to each other, so prints them as separate. Are you able to use LuaLatex (and `luacolor` package)?

Comment: coloring components of glyphs are difficult for various reasons. With lualatex you have a few more options. See section 4-6 here https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2020-UFi-TUB-tb127fischer-bangla.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling your code with lualatex, I get:

[image: colours]

MWE

```
% Compile with lualatex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari]

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\newcommand{\green}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}

\begin{document}

श्री:
    
श्\green{र}\red{ी}ः 

\end{document}
```

---

**Addendum**

For the ligatures, a combination of font and font renderer is involved.

Also, the glyph to be coloured according to the code, may not be the actual ligature glyph that is substituted in during ligature formation (it will depend on the font designer's intention).

[image: table]

MWE

```
% Compile with lualatex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand\ffontaname{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\newcommand\ffontbname{Lohit Devanagari}
\newcommand\ffontcname{Akshar Unicode}
\newcommand\ffontdname{Aparajita}
\newcommand\ffontename{Baloo}
\newcommand\ffontfname{Samyak Devanagari}
\newcommand\ffontgname{Sanskrit Text}
\newcommand\ffonthname{Sumana}
\newcommand\ffontiname{Mangal}
\newcommand\ffontjname{Nakula}
\newcommand\ffontkname{Samanata}
\newcommand\ffontlname{Kalimati}
\newcommand\ffontmname{FreeSerif}
\newcommand\ffontnname{Anek Devanagari Medium}
\newcommand\ffontoname{Shobhika}


\newfontface\ffonta{\ffontaname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=Node]
\newfontface\ffontb{\ffontbname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=Node]
\newfontface\ffontc{\ffontcname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=Node]
\newfontface\ffontd{\ffontdname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=Node]
\newfontface\ffonte{\ffontename}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=Node]
\newfontface\ffontf{\ffontgname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=Node]
\newfontface\ffontg{\ffontgname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=Node]
\newfontface\ffonth{\ffonthname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=Node]
\newfontface\ffonti{\ffontiname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=Node]
\newfontface\ffontj{\ffontjname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=Node]
\newfontface\ffontk{\ffontkname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=Node]
\newfontface\ffontl{\ffontlname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=Node]
\newfontface\ffontm{\ffontmname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=Node]
\newfontface\ffontn{\ffontnname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=Node]
\newfontface\ffonto{\ffontoname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=Node]

\newfontface\ffontah{\ffontaname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]
\newfontface\ffontbh{\ffontbname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]
\newfontface\ffontch{\ffontcname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]
\newfontface\ffontdh{\ffontdname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]
\newfontface\ffonteh{\ffontename}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]
\newfontface\ffontfh{\ffontfname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]
\newfontface\ffontgh{\ffontgname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]
\newfontface\ffonthh{\ffonthname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]
\newfontface\ffontih{\ffontiname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]
\newfontface\ffontjh{\ffontjname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]
\newfontface\ffontkh{\ffontkname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]
\newfontface\ffontlh{\ffontlname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]
\newfontface\ffontmh{\ffontmname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]
\newfontface\ffontnh{\ffontnname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]
\newfontface\ffontoh{\ffontoname}[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]

\newcommand\testtext{श्री \color{blue}श्\color{green}र\color{red}^^^^0940\color{black}}
\newcommand\dotest[1]{%
\csname ffont#1name\endcsname &%
\csname ffont#1\endcsname\testtext &%
\csname ffont#1h\endcsname\testtext \\}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
Font & Renderer=Node & Renderer=HarfBuzz \\ \hline
\dotest{a}
\dotest{b}
\dotest{c}
\dotest{d}
\dotest{e}
\dotest{f}
\dotest{g}
\dotest{h}
\dotest{i}
\dotest{j}
\dotest{k}
\dotest{l}
\dotest{m}
\dotest{n}
\dotest{o}
\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. The reason I don't use LuaLatex is that as in the output that you saw, it doesn't render the glyph correctly. श्री: is the correct rendering, not श् रीः

Comment: I realized that I have a very old lualatex. I will upgrade and update. Thanks

Comment: @PradyumnaAchar Current lualatex uses HarfBuzz renderer (like xelatex), but, for ligatures, it also depends on the font designer, too. See addition to answer.