# input Chandra Bindu in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, indic, devanagari

I am trying to get a Chandra Bindu in Devanagari in XeLaTeX using the RomDev mapping technique (https://github.com/somadeva/RomDev).

But I don't know what is the equivalent Roman letter to achieve that.

There is an open issue in somadeva's GitHub project page. But no answer there.

https://github.com/somadeva/RomDev/issues/1

Therefore, I am asking the question here.

Comment: Remark, you would be more likely to receive an answer if you rewrite the question to be understandable by a English speaker.

Comment: I have no idea what exactly you are trying to achieve … There is Unicode U+0310 COMBINING CANDRABINDU but an MWE would be immensely helpful. Something like तालँओकान्?

Comment: I don't think I can help with the mapping, but just a question, do you _need_ to input a romanised form?, you could, with xetex, input the devanagari directly

Comment: Looks like the mapping file is using `ĩ`, `õ` (U+0129, U+00F5). Try copy-pasting the letters in. `^^^^0901` could also work as direct input, but you have not supplied sample MWE code (and `.tec` file) to test against, so is a guess. Much better to use lualatex/fontspec (and Shobhika font or similar) and polyglossia or babel package for Devanagari.

Comment: Search for "devanagari" on this site. Possibly helpful for direct input: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638563/using-multiple-colors-within-a-compound-glyph/638573#638573
 and 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630516/how-to-use-devanagari-variable-font-in-latex/630608#630608